# MySQL Create two columns from a table with one column

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join, self-join

I am really new to MySQL, below is one of my first statement basically:)

I need help.

### I have this table definition in mysql:

### id | item_id | price | def = could be `A` or `B`

I need to build a new table with two columns out of this one where I will have
items grouped by price and separated into items with def = A and def = B

I've tried to use self join and it creates two columns, but it groups only by price of def = A, not distinctly by price of A and price of B.

This is where I've gotten so far:

```
SELECT a.`id` as A_id,  a.`item_id` as A_ITEM_id, a.`def` as A_def, a.price as A_PRICE,
b.`id` as B_id,  b.`item_id` as B_ITEM_id, b.`def` as B_def, b.price as B_PRICE

FROM table as a, table as b where 
a.`def` = 'A' AND b.`def` = 'B' GROUP by A_PRICE;
```

I've tried to group by A_PRICE,B_PRICE - doesn't really work.

Comment: I think you should clarify exactly what data must be in the two columns of your new table. If you could even provide some example (initial data, expected result) that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `case based aggregation` to convert def row values into columns

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/955915/5)**

```
select item_id, price,
       max(case when def='A' then 'A' end) as A, 
       max(case when def='B' then 'B' end) as B
from table1
group by item_id, price
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! With a few adjustments it did what I needed to achieve.